# What is the prettiest way to make deferred wait for async ndb calls?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

```
deferred.defer(f,e)

function f(e):
  e.put_async()
```

Changes to `e` are discarded in the SDK and presumably on production too. One obvious way to solve the problem is to store all rpc's and get_result() them, but this is not pretty.

Is there a way to make this function ndb-compatible?

This function is used in multiple parts of the code, normal requests are `@ndb.toplevel`, so there is no problem for them.

Comment: any reason to use async and defer task together?

Comment: the actual function is more complex than this, async is always better or equal in performance

Comment: I am not sure but the sdk @ndb.tasklet feature looks like can define the whole function to run async. Therefore, i guess it should run just like defered task. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/async#tasklets

Answer (score 2):

The function that you defer can't be an `@ndb.toplevel`, but you can have that call a function that is:

```
def f(e):
  g(e)

@ndb.toplevel
def g(e):
  e.put_async()
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, so can ndb.toplevel used recursively, a request with ndb.toplevel, calling f, would it create problems?

Comment: if f is called with deferred.defer, then it is operating in a different request context, so no nesting. (I don't know if nesting will cause problems.)